# Using Regex with Symbols such as "<"

Tags: java, regex

I have a String `<Thread> 'data we need' </Thread>` and I want to extract `'data we need'`.

I've been using this, but it doesn't have any results:

```
Pattern patternThread = Pattern.compile("<Thread(.*?)/Thread>");
Matcher matcherThread = patternThread.matcher(a);
if (matcherThread.find()) {
    System.out.println("Thread Oke");
    System.out.println(matcherThread.group(1));
}
```

I know the problem was the `"<" and the "/"`.

So, any suggestions?
i have already tried the "//" and "/"
is it my jdk to old? its at 7.2
i have searched the solution on oracle but still doesn't go through this problem

Comment: Escape the chars with ` \\ `

Comment: Read up on java regular expressions here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: how about the / ?

Comment: still can't do, don't know why

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse XML.

Comment: done converting it to just Strings @Qix

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex instead `<Thread>(.*?)</Thread>`:

```
Pattern patternThread = Pattern.compile("<Thread>(.*?)</Thread>");
Matcher matcherThread = patternThread.matcher("<Thread> 'data we need' </Thread>");
while (matcherThread.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcherThread.group(1));
}
```

**Output**

```
 'data we need'
```

1. You can use `while` in case you can get multiple result
2. You have to use `matcherThread.group(1)` instead of `matcherThread.group()` because this last return `<Thread> 'data we need' </Thread>`

You can find a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/9gSpLw/1), and you can find a code example [here](https://ideone.com/LsnYtA)

Comment: still no results, sorry @YCF_L

Comment: what did you mean @SetiawanCandrafu no results?

Comment: can i get your email @YCF_L? ill send u part of my source code. even with ur code, my netbeans ide doesnt show anything except the build succesfull notice

Comment: @SetiawanCandrafu you can put your code here https://ideone.com/ and you can save it and show me the link like i do

Comment: ok @SetiawanCandrafu you try to parse an XML file with regex, and this is not practice, this information about your String is not set in your question, so i can help you just in this case but it is not practice so here is what i can do hope this can help you https://ideone.com/WnkuQf, you can find explication in the solution

Comment: thank you, ill improve my question next time, thank you again

Comment: one last question, is it because the "\n" ?

Comment: yes @SetiawanCandrafu it is because the `\n` because you copy past your xml information :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip the apostrophes too, then you can use this regex too: `\\s*<Thread[^>]*>[^']*'(.*?)'.*?</Thread>\\s*`.

Explanation:

- **Update:** `\\s*` at the beginning of the pattern will match some white spaces, including new lines
- `<Thread[^>]*` will match the full `<Thread>` tag, even with attributes
- `[^']*` will match every character up to the first apostrophe
- `'(.*?)'` will match everything between the apostrophes. However, the apostrophes are **outside** of the of the group. So all you capture is the stuff between the apostrophes.
- `.*?</Thread>` lazily matches everything up the closing `</Thread>` tag
- **Update:** `\\s*` at the end of the pattern will match some white spaces, including new lines

This is the full code:

```
// Update: the pattern tolerates white spaces at both ends of the regex
Pattern patternThread = Pattern.compile("\\s*<Thread[^>]*>[^']*'(.*?)'.*?</Thread>\\s*");
// Update: string below contains newline
Matcher matcherThread = patternThread.matcher("<Thread> 'data we need' </Thread>\r\n");
if (matcherThread.find()) {
    System.out.println("Thread Oke");
    System.out.println(matcherThread.group(1));
}
```

The output is:

```
Thread Oke
data we need
```

Comment: thank you, but when i put the "<Thread> 'data we need' </Thread>" into a variable first, it doesn't show any results, why is that? i already tried @YCF_L method and yours but still

Comment: It shows me some results though. I believe some the characters in that variable aren't really what you think they are. Can you *paste* the related code here as a comment?

Comment: thank you for answering and the problem is "\n", sorry for not stating the real problem. and thank you again

Comment: In this case we can add `\\s*` to the end of the pattern. Updating the answer accordingly